# FEAL-4 Fk Function 4 Rounds

Tags: encryption, feal

As I understood in FEAL-4 it needs 4 pair of round keys. Which means that we need to launch Fk function 4 times.

My problem occurs starting the 2nd round. At the first round we have the original 64 bits key; which is sliced to 32 bits. So on the output of 1st round we have 32 bit key. But the 2nd, 3rd and 4th round also require a 64 bit key.

What should I do on the 2nd round? After the 1st round I have only 32 bit key. Does it means that 2nd part should be filled with 0's?

Comment: Please indicate what you don't understand from the "Key Schedule diagram" in the [FEAL specification](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/spring2013/482/team/g1/report.pdf) linked to by Dsthro. It seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell about the FEAL family by doing a little bit of research, the inputs for the FK function are two 32-bit sub-keys, each of which are half of the 64-bit key.

http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/spring2013/482/team/g1/report.pdf

Contains some instruction on the FK function you are asking about.

Comment: That link to the spec is pretty useful, but your description of the Fk function seems off.